# passing id through menu item android

Tags: android, menuitem

I am loading menu items in navigation drawer dynamically. With the help of `setOnMenuItemClickListener(new MenuItem.OnMenuItemClickListener()` I am trying to fetch and pass `id` from database to the next activity, but when I click on a menu item its displaying the most recent id and then again the 1st id. How do I get this right?

```
 public void addDynamic() {
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(final String response) {

                    try {
                        jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                        jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("list");
                        submenu = menu.addSubMenu("Test");
                        for (int i = 0; i <jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                            jsonObject1 = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                            a = submenu.add(jsonObject1.getString("name"));
                            a.setIcon(new IconicsDrawable(MainActivity.this)
                                    .icon(FontAwesome.Icon.faw_flask)
                                    .sizeDp(24));
                            a.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new MenuItem.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                                    try {
                                        JSONObject object = new JSONObject(response);
                                        JSONArray array = object.getJSONArray("list");
                                       for (int i = 0; i <array.length(); i++) {
                                            JSONObject object1 = array.getJSONObject(i);
                                            id = object1.getString("id");
                                            Bundle b = new Bundle();
                                            b.putString("id", id);
                                            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, TestDetails.class);
                                            intent.putExtra("fid", b);
                                            startActivity(intent);
                                        }
                                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    }
                                        return false;
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    }
                    catch (JSONException e) {
                        Log.e("Error", "Failed" + e.toString());
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Log.e("Error", "Try Later" + error.toString());
                }
            });
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(MainActivity.this);
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
}

@Override
protected void attachBaseContext(Context newBase) {
    super.attachBaseContext(IconicsContextWrapper.wrap(newBase));
}
```

Comment: why you using **Intent** in `for loop` ...?

Comment: a.setOnMenuItemClickListene in this line what's the data type of a and is it a global value ?? you should create a local value after parsing from json and add listener to that then the listener will be respective to all what you created menu item

Comment: @ Masum Biswas a is menuitem declared globally. Could u please elaborate . I am a beginner

Answer (score 0):

in `intent.putExtra()` use String value of `id` like below

```
 JSONObject object1 = array.getJSONObject(i);
 id = object1.getString("id");
 //Bundle b = new Bundle(); remove this line
 //b.putString("id", id); also remove this line
 Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, TestDetails.class);
 intent.putExtra("fid", id);
```

for fetching intent bundle values try below code

```
    final Intent intent = getIntent();
    Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();

    if(bundle != null){
        String FID = bundle.getString("fid");
     }
```

Comment: Intent intent = getIntent();
        Bundle b = intent.getBundleExtra("fid");
         id = b.getString("id"); Is this right way to fetch in next activity?

Comment: OkThank you. The problem is still same even if i put intent out of loop, activity is opening twice and both id's are going to next intent. there are 2 for loops.

Answer (score 0):

What are you doing here ???

```
public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                                try {
                                    JSONObject object = new JSONObject(response);
                                    JSONArray array = object.getJSONArray("list");
                                   for (int i = 0; i <array.length(); i++) {
                                        JSONObject object1 = array.getJSONObject(i);
                                        id = object1.getString("id");
                                        Bundle b = new Bundle();
                                        b.putString("id", id);
                                        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, TestDetails.class);
                                        intent.putExtra("fid", b);
                                        startActivity(intent);
                                    }
                                } catch (JSONException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                                    return false;
                            }
```

Please notice to for loop! If your loop executes multiple time so what will happen ? Suppose the array length = 2 then it will iterate two times and for one click on item it will start two activity with there respected value [id] that's means

```
                                    Bundle b = new Bundle();
                                    b.putString("id", id);
                                    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, TestDetails.class);
                                    intent.putExtra("fid", b);
                                    startActivity(intent);
```

These code will execute two times and start two activity consecutively and you will see the last activity. First fix this may your problem will fix. Add a condition as if for your one click only one activity will be started.

Comment: I put the intent out of the for loop but still its executing twice